# .next plus .toggle not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, toggle, slidetoggle

I am using .toggle plus .next to slideUp/Down the li which is working fine every where except IE 8-7 which is quit weird, I would like to mention that this code is working when I am using it on my local PC but after uploading to server it doesn't work. I am using the following html.

```
<ul id="search_list">
     <li class="ques"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Lorem ipsum dolor malesuada.</a></li>
     <li class="ans"><div class="arw"></div>Lorem ipsum dolor malesuada.</li>
     <li class="ques"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Lorem ipsum dolor malesuada.</a></li>
     <li class="ans"><div class="arw"></div>Lorem ipsum dolor malesuada.</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried the following jquery code.

```
$("#search_list li.ques").live('click', function(){
    $(this).next("li.ans").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

and

```
$("#search_list li.ques").toggle(function(){
    $(this).next('li.ans').slideDown();
}, function(){
    $(this).next('li.ans').slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me in IE 7/8: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BigBagel/7Z296/1/embedded/result/) | [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BigBagel/7Z296/2/). Are you getting any console errors? Also, use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of live; live was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9. I'd also use `event.preventDefault()` ([reference](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)) instead of inline javascript. Here's a code example with those changes: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BigBagel/7Z296/3/).

Comment: both of your attempts work. http://jsfiddle.net/VKNMz/ http://jsfiddle.net/VKNMz/1/ are you using jQuery 1.9, where both of those methods have been removed? If so, IE8 has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention one important thing that it works when I am working on my PC, but when i upload it to server it doesnt work. I am using jquery-1.7.2

Comment: Is IE8 the only browser affected? or did you put that in the title just because it's the only browser you tested in. If it is the only browser affected, did you restart all of your browsers and try again to avoid cache?

Comment: @KevinB yes IE-8-7 are the ones which are effected, and no there isnt any cache issue.

Comment: Okay I figured out the problem, I was using following conditional comments for IE, after removing this the code works, but I need those conditional comments.


<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie7 lt_ie9"><![endif]-->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out the problem, I was using a plugin [fastLiveFilter](https://github.com/awbush/jquery-fastLiveFilter) on same page, I moved its function below my show/hide toggle script and it works fine now in IE 7-8.

Thanks for your comments guys.